# Python Lambda boto3 Unknown service: 'scheduler' error

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to create a EventBridgeScheduler client in my Python 3.9.15 Lambda, but the service responds with `UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'scheduler'`. Isn't this service supported even though it's included in boto3's [official documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/scheduler.html#EventBridgeScheduler.Client.delete_schedule)? The list included in the error message doesn't include `scheduler` among Valid service names.

```
import boto3

eb_client = boto3.client('scheduler')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(json.dumps(event))

    schedule_name = event['resources']
    delete_schedule(schedule_name)


def delete_schedule(name):
    try:
        response = eb_client.delete_schedule(
            Name=name
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scheduler feature [was added](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#1267) to boto3 in `v1.26.7`. The Lambda Python [runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) currently come with `v1.20.32`.

[Package up](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html) the latest SDK version with your Lambda to use the EventBridge scheduler client.